# Regular expression for length validation in email address

Tags: regex

We have a textbox which accepts comma separated email address. The regular expression is

```
^(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*[,]?\b)*$.
```

However now I am unable to add a length validation to this expression. Each email address should not be more than 150 characters.  I have tried

```
^((\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)){1,150}\s*[,]?\b)*$.
```

But it doesn't work.
Can you please modify the regex so that it also implements this validation too.

Comment: What are you using to display the form?  It may be easier to set a size attribute on the text field.  e.g. in html `<textfield size="20"/>`

Comment: The text field accepts comma seperated email addresslike

gg@gg.com,tt@tt.com. The length validation has to be done for each individual email address. Each email address lenth should no be more than 150 characters. So I can't set size attribute on the text field.

Comment: Why limit email addresses to 150 chars? Seems pretty arbitrary to me.

Comment: Probably to fit in a database column. Seems a reasonably high limit - I suspect a lot of places limit it much below that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather not complicate this regex further and add explicit length check before checking that e-mail matches. In JavaScript it will be something like the following:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*[,]?\b)*$/;
    // 20 is used instead of 150 for sake of example
    return email.length <= 20 && regex.test(email);
}
// validateEmail("jdoe@example.com") == true
// validateEmail("loooooooooooooooooooonjohn@example.com") == false
```

By the way, dot after `$` in your regex seems to be a mistake, so I skipped it in my snippet.

Comment: Think it's better to implement this. Thought I would do this without javascript validation and alert box, since rest of the textboxes on the page have validators to show error messages. However, don't think I have a choice in this.

Comment: There's one more thing. The text box accepts comma separated email address. So return email.length <= 20 && regex.test(email); wont work. I will have to split and individually check length of each email address.

Comment: Of course, I meant single email but not content of text box as a whole. So, yes, you need to split.

Answer (score 5):

Why use a regexp when you can simply check the length of the string? If you must, use a second regexp:

```
^.{1,150}$
```

Comment: I went this route (adding a 2nd validator expression) because you really want 2 different messages for these validators. If someone enters a 151 character email and the message says the email format is invalid, that's not helpful. It's better to have a 2nd message that says "address too long".

Answer (score 5):

Use a lookahead

```
/(?=^.{1,150}$)(your regex goes here)/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]){0,70}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for a way to extend my `ng-pattern` for e-mail for an Angular form.

Taking Rorick's approach of checking for length separately, I found a much easier solution: just set `ng-maxlength="150"` in the input. Then you can customize an error message that tells the user that the e-mail is too long.

`maxlength="150"` works fine too, preventing any extra characters from being added to the field, but I liked that `ng-maxlength` tells you what's wrong rather than truncating your string.